# List’s contextual menu issue with ie 6

Tags: list, custom-actions

I have a list with a large amount of items. When scrolling down to edit/view an item which is at the bottom of the page, the contextual menu appears on top of the page not by the item so I have to scroll up to click an element of the contextual menu.

This issue only appears with IE6.

(Using MOSS 2007.)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happening a lot with custom master pages and CSS. IE6 differs a lot from other browsers regarding item positioning. Please check your CSS.